# VMWare Workstation Internal error

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

So I have been trying to get a BMW Diagnostic system running in VMWare going. Everything goes fine till I finish installing and restart to use the new OS. Keep getting an error, a Vcpu-0 double fault of some sort

After doing some researching online it seems that its a fault between processors? Well here is a dropbox link to the logs files, the core file and dump files generated by VMWare.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwkrgcrtfhq29wc/vmware-vmx-8256.dmp?dl=0

It worked fine in Virtual box but I couldn't get it to communicate with the host computer as virtualbox wouldn't keep network settings.

To add im runnning windows 10 home and vmware workstation 6.5.2

Answer (score 0):

[Vmware workstation 6.5.2](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws65/doc/releasenotes_ws652.html) is extremely old. Windows 10 is only supported starting with Version 11. So update to the latest version 12.1, to get the best experience.

Comment: Oh really? I thought it was the newest! Well thanks I'll try it

Comment: no, this version is from 2009, which is extremely old.

Comment: does the new VMware 12 fixes it?